# Nginx config. File from disk with check

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I dont understand how i can write logic : if file in folder exists then return;

```
location ~ "/((\w{2})[\w-]+\.(png|jpg))$" {

    if(-f e:\\ThumbFull\\$2\\$1){
        alias  e:\\ThumbFull\\$2\\$1;   
    }

    if(-f e:\\Image\\$2\\$1){
        alias  e:\\Image\\$2\\$1;   
    }
    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `root` to a common parent directory (i.e. `e:/`) and use `try_files` to check for the file in both directories.

For example:

```
location ~ "/((\w{2})[\w-]+\.(png|jpg))$" {
    root e:/;
    try_files /ThumbFull/$2/$1 /Image/$2/$1 =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: oh its work!  very many difference information... and i dont know that try_files work with regex . Thx !